# PHP Change default value for Select list

Tags: php, select

I have this little issue with the price form for my Joomla backend.
The default value is always "nothing", so I just need to set "Euro" as default (see screenshot).
I'm pretty newbie with PHP, so I can't do it by myself..
Here is the part of code that realizes this form:

```
$htmlPrice = '<div class="jomcomdevPriceRow">';
        $htmlPrice .= '<div class="control-group" style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;">';
        $htmlPrice .= '<label> '.JText::_('COM_JOMCOMDEV_FIELD_PRICE_NETTO').'</label><input type="text" name="' . $this->name.'[price_netto][]" id="' . $this->id . 'ValueNetto"' . ' value="" />';
        $htmlPrice .= '</div>';
        $htmlPrice .= '<div class="control-group" style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;">';
        $htmlPrice .= str_replace("\n", '', '<label is="jform_featured-lbl"> '.JText::_('COM_JOMCOMDEV_FIELDSET_PRICE_GROUP').'</label>'.JHtml::_('select.genericlist', JHtml::_('jdcategory.options', 'com_jomestate.price', array('onlyroot' => 0)),  $this->name.'[type_id][]',"", 'value',  'text', null,  true)); 
        $htmlPrice .= '</div>';
        $htmlPrice .= '</div>';
```

I hope I'm clear enough. Thank you in advance.

Screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ix39.png

**UPDATE**

Hmm, I don't know really where is configured this element. Here is full code, maybe I'm looking a wrong part..

```
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' ); 


class JFormFieldJdPrice extends JFormField

{
    /**
     * @var    string   The form field type.
     * @since  11.1
     */
    public $type = 'JdAddress';

    /**
     * Method to get the field input markup.
     *
     * @return  string   The field input markup.
     *
     * @since   11.1
     */
    public function getInput()
    {
        $id = JRequest::getInt('id');
//        if(empty($id)) {
//            $html = '<div style="padding: 10px; margin: 10px 0;">';
//            $html .= JText::_('COM_JOMCOMDEV_PRICEADD_NOID_INFO');
//            $html .= '</div>';
//            return $html;
//        }

        $htmlPrice = '<div class="jomcomdevPriceRow">';
        $htmlPrice .= '<div class="control-group" style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;">';
        $htmlPrice .= '<label> '.JText::_('COM_JOMCOMDEV_FIELD_PRICE_NETTO').'</label><input type="text" name="' . $this->name.'[price_netto][]" id="' . $this->id . 'ValueNetto"' . ' value="" />';
        $htmlPrice .= '</div>';
        $htmlPrice .= '<div class="control-group" style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;">';
        $htmlPrice .= str_replace("\n", '', '<label is="jform_featured-lbl"> '.JText::_('COM_JOMCOMDEV_FIELDSET_PRICE_GROUP').'</label>'.JHtml::_('select.genericlist', JHtml::_('jdcategory.options', 'com_jomestate.price', array('onlyroot' => 0)),  $this->name.'[type_id][]',"", 'value',  'text', null,  true)); 
        $htmlPrice .= '</div>';
        $htmlPrice .= '</div>';


        $link = JURI::root()."index.php?option=com_jomcomdev&format=raw&task=ajax.price&name=first&id=";
        $runScript = "
            window.addEvent('domready', function() {
            var options = {htmlPrice: '".$htmlPrice."', link: '".$link."', selector: $$('#".$this->id."')};
                  Comdev.price.init(options);
            });            
        ";
        $document = JFactory::getDocument();

        $document->addScriptDeclaration($runScript);

        JText::script('COM_JOMCOMDEV_JS_BUTTON_ADD'); 
        JText::script('COM_JOMCOMDEV_JS_BUTTON_DELETE'); 
        JText::script('COM_JOMCOMDEV_JS_BUTTON_OPTION'); 

        JText::script('COM_JOMCOMDEV_FIELD_PRICE_NETTO'); 

        $html = '';
        $html .= '<div id="'.$this->id.'">';

if(!empty($id)) {
            $data = Main_Price::get($id, (string) $this->element['extension']);

            foreach($data AS $d) {
                $html .= '<div class="jomcomdevPriceRow">';
                $html .= '<div class="control-group" style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;">';
                $html .= '<label is="jform_featured-lbl"> '.JText::_('COM_JOMCOMDEV_FIELD_PRICE_NETTO').'</label><input type="text" name="' . $this->name.'[price_netto][]" id="' . $this->id . 'ValueNetto"' . ' value="'.$d->price_netto.'" />';
                $html .= '</div>'; 
                $html .= '<div class="control-group" style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;">';
                $html .= '<label is="jform_featured-lbl"> '.JText::_('COM_JOMCOMDEV_FIELDSET_PRICE_GROUP').'</label>'.JHtml::_('select.genericlist',  JHtml::_('jdcategory.options', 'com_jomestate.price', array('onlyroot' => 0)), $this->name.'[type_id][]', 'value', null, 'text', $d->type_id,  true); 
                $html .= '</div>';
                $html .= '<div class="control-group" style="padding-top: 17px;">';
                $html .= '<label></label><a href="#" onclick="Comdev.price.del(this)" class="btn btn-danger">'.JText::_('COM_JOMCOMDEV_JS_BUTTON_DELETE').'</a>';
                $html .= '</div>';
                $html .= '</div>';
                $html .= '<div class="clr"></div>';
            }
        }


        $html .= '</div>';

        return $html;

    }
}
```

Comment: Is that code you have written or Joomla code? I think you are looking in the wrong place, that looks to be the code that renders an element, you need to find where you configure the element.

Comment: This code is written by real estate component's guys.